# How to change BigQuery scopes?

Tags: scope, google-bigquery, domo

I am trying to write a query that pulls from federated tables in BQ. In BQ I can run the query and get results. However, when I run the same query in Domo, I get the error: Domo is ready, but received a Access Denied: BigQuery BigQuery: No OAuth token with Google Drive scope was found..Please contact the data provider for support.

I have read all over the place that I need to change the scope to do this. I am not a developer though, so I am not sure exactly how to go about this in BQ.

Does anyone have step by step instructions for how to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to illustrate the specific problem you're having in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Answer (score 0):

When you created federated table you grant access of account that run query on the file in e.g. Google Drive.
So when you run query in BQ Console - it used your credentials.
When you run from domo - it may use different account (probably some service account) - so to have everything work you should grant proper access (essentially share document with this account) to your drive file to this account.